# Passing previous URL into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

What I essentially wish to do is have a bookmark link that, when clicked, performs an action on the current (or in effect, previous) URL. I have seen this achieved with Youtube converters etc.

I have tried accessing the previous URL using document.referrer but it does not work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) != -1){
     $referURL =  document.referrer;
     console.log($referURL);
  }
});
```

Comment: What's doesn't work?

Comment: The code I just showed you